# Android ListView performance

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-adapter

In our Android application we've got a ListView filled with active chatsessions between different users. There's no real limit to how many active chatsessions a user can have, so obviously there's no limit to how many items this ListView contains either.

**Each ListView item consists of:**

- 1x inflated View holding several images
- 1x ImageView
- 1x String

Everything works out the way we want to in terms of loading times and in terms of looks and composition. While the ListView contains below 20-ish items, everything is ok. As soon as the ListView starts containing above those 20-ish items, the performance turns gradually more and more unbearable for each item added.

I've been doing some trial and error testing, trying to disable each element and component of the item structure, and what I've found is that the performance drop happens whenever we have ***any*** kind of image in the items. So no matter what kind, any image causes the performance to suck, when the ListView contains more than 20-ish items. How do I optimize this? I've attached the getView from our adapter + our method for adding the photos.

Any and all help and/or suggestions are appreciated :)

**getView from our adapter:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    System.out.println("getview:"+position+" "+convertView);

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    Match match = matches.get(position);

    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.matches_list_item,  parent, false);

        viewHolder = initViewHolder(convertView, match);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    addGroupPhoto(imageSize, match, viewHolder, false);

    if (match.matchedGroup != null) {

        viewHolder.names.setText(match.matchedGroup.getMembersNames());
        viewHolder.matchedText.setText(match.latestMessage.value == null ?
                String.format(mContext.getString(R.string.matched_on), getFormatedMatchDate(match.matchedOn)) : match.latestMessage.value);

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

**addGroupPhoto from our adapter**

```
private void addGroupPhoto(int imageSize, Match match, ViewHolder viewHolder,     boolean isSelected) {

    if (viewHolder.groupPhoto.findViewById(R.id.unseen_messages) != null) {
        viewHolder.groupPhoto.removeView(viewHolder.groupPhoto.findViewById(R.id.unseen_messages));
    }

    if (match.matchedGroup != null) {
        RelativeLayout lay = Utilities.createGroupImagePhoto(mContext, imageSize, imageSize, match.matchedGroup.members, Utilities.GROUP_PHOTO_MODE_GROUP_WITHOUT_NAMES);
        ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)lay.getLayoutParams()).addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)lay.getLayoutParams()).addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
        ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)lay.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(smallMargin, 0, 0, 0);
        viewHolder.groupPhoto.addView(lay);
        lay.invalidate();
    }

    ImageView crop = new ImageView(mContext);
    crop.setBackgroundResource(getCropImageDrawable(isSelected));
    crop.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageSize,imageSize));
    ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)crop.getLayoutParams()).addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)crop.getLayoutParams()).addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
    ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)crop.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(smallMargin, 0, 0, 0);

    int marginForMessage = 0;

    viewHolder.groupPhoto.addView(crop);
    if (!match.seen | match.newMessages > 0) {
        addMessages(match.newMessages,  marginForMessage, viewHolder);
    }
}
```

EDIT: This was caused by programmatically adding the images. After adding the images and their different attributes inside the XML-file, instead of adding them and declaring their parameters programmatically, everything is working smoothly.

Comment: While you do anything correct regarding the View-recycling you should definitly consider using Picasso for Image Loading
http://square.github.io/picasso/ also changing layout params at runtime is not the best way - a scale type like centerCrop or fitCenter could do your job for the imageview i think - also you should have the views in your XML and just change visibility of the items for better performance instead of creating or removing them at runtime

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - we're also looking into optimizing how we generally handle our images. However, the performance drop in our ListView persists even with a single ImageView with a small, optimized png-file loaded from our resources. I doubt using Picasso (or similarly available libraries) would solve our performance issue.

Comment: i would defintily give it a try at picasso - also put the imageview inside the xml and set it to gone on standard and after your if set visibility either to gone or visible - this should also help improve the performance.

Comment: Yeah, I might've been to quick on my first comment. Trying out Picasso now - will also try out your XML-related suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the problem seems to be that you are adding `View`s and setting their `LayoutParams` programmatically in your `Adapter`. This is inherently "heavier" than setting it in XML, and would become even more noticeable on low and medium-end devices.

Unless you have a compelling reason for adding `View`s in this way, you shouldn't. `Picasso` won't help you here.

**Note:** A small thing I've noticed is that you haven't called

```
convertView.setTag(holder);
```

in your `getView()` method. This omission can also be a source of performance problems.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the programmatic settings of parameters fixed it. Included all ImageViews inside the XML-file now - smooth, smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

An additional consideration is that in `addGroupPhoto()` you're making at least one more `findViewById()` per list item.

The *sole* purpose of ViewHolder pattern is to cache the references to views, i.e. only call `findViewById` when you're setting up your ViewHolder for the first time.